# Extract javascript generated content of certain page

Tags: javascript, php, xpath

I want to extract the content of the following section container:

```
<section class="tiw-line-name " id="EU-group-holiday-line-0" data-side="both">
<a href="/event=479/darkmoon-faire"><img src="https://wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/tiny/calendar_darkmoonfaireelwynnstart.gif">Darkmoon Faire</a>
</section>
```

Normally I use XPath like that:

```
$xpath->query('//*[contains(@id, "EU-group-holiday-line")]');
```

Now the problem is that this site seems to use javascript to generate this content. Also I don't see any XHR request, which would help.

Is there any chance to extract the data anyways?

To make it more clear. This is not my website. I need to crawl it.

This is the complete page:

https://www.wowhead.com/today-in-wow

Comment: Have a look at selenium. `https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver` It uses a browser-instance that also let's JavaScript do it's thing and when ready , you can use XPath to find your requested content

Answer (score 0):

You are right that this website uses client-side javascript and does not use additional XHR requests for the mentioned data. So we may expect that the data is inside initially loaded code (HTML+JS). Searching for something like `event=643` (similar to your `event=479`) in the code confirms our suggestion and results in the required JSON-formatted substring (I've added indents):

```
{
   "icon": "calendar_weekendmistsofpandariastart",
   "name": "Timewalking Dungeon Event",
   "side": "both",
   "url": "/event=643/timewalking-dungeon-event"
},
```

So you see that extracted data contains the required data and we may use a variety of tools to crawl it.